# new offsetHeight does not calculated after updating font size

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, dynamic

I have a problem regarding 'offsetHeight' property does not get updated after updating font size. Bellow is the code.

```
function shrink_toolbar_text()
{
  var toolbar = document.getElementById("toolbar");
  var icons = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-alone");

  var icon_size = 64;
  var icon_height = icons[0].offsetHeight ;

  while( icon_height > toolbar.offsetHeight)
  {


   // textSpan.style.fontSize = parseInt(textSpan.style.fontSize) - 1;
    icon_size = icon_size -1;
    for ( i=0; i< icons.length ;i++){
      icons[i].style.fontSize = icon_size ; 
    }  

     icon_height = icons[0].offsetHeight ;
    console.log( icon_height);
    console.log( icon_size);
    // console.log( parseInt(icon_size));
  }
  console.log("shrink_toolbar_text() ");
}
```

any workaround on this situation ?
I've tried following things so far.
1. Try to redraw each and every icons using show and hide.
2. Tried 'getComputedStyle()' but it don't return a value called 'offsetHeight' at all.

Any idea why code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The code should be corrected to this.

```
var icon_size = 64px;
```

and

```
icons[i].style.fontSize = icon_size+"px" ;
```

In some browsers, this code won't work without postfix 'px'. Neither it emit a error message on console. So careful coding on this.